# Confusing PHP Logic

Tags: php, logic

So I got a [PHP](https://www.php.net/) question in a paper. The question is to write  the output of the given code.

```
$x = 5;
echo $x;
echo "<br />";
echo $x+++$x++;
echo "<br />";
echo $x;
echo "<br />";
echo $x---$x--;
echo "<br />";
echo $x;
```

So my answer was

```
5
12
5
0
5
```

This is what everyone wrote because it's the logically correct answer but when we practically implemented it the output was this.

```
5
11
7
1
5
```

Can someone explain to me how and why PHP would give this output? It's very confusing.

Comment: For learning purposes, this seems ok but if you ever write any production level code like `$x+++$x++`, you will be fired then and there. So, don't take these kind of pre/post increments too seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you need to know is that `$x++` uses the value, then increments it, while `$x--` uses the value, the decrements it. So break down the code:

```
$x = 5;  // Easy enough
echo $x++ + $x++; // X is first 5. Use it, then increment it. X is now 6, use it, then increment it.  5+6 = 11
echo $x; // Since we incremented it again on the previous line, x is now 7. 
echo $x-- - $x--; // Use 7, decrement (x is now 6), subtract X, then decrement it. 7 - 6 = 1
echo $x; //  X is now 5
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php , it has more information and examples on how it works.

Comment: Ah... so the variable value is 1st used then incremented. Thanks for the explanation.